# why SELECT query cannot come first and then EDIT query

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

this web app is a table with member data   and if I click edit, it will link to edit page that has selected the member data already so it should be SELECT first

but
why SELECT query cannot write first  and then write EDIT query.
I try to move the SELECT section code to be above  but when to run the program, it cannot edit (not work)
PS. If I write like below it works fine.  but I would like to know the reason.

```
public function editMember($id)
{
    //UPDATE 
    if($this->input->post("btn") != null)
    {
        $arr = array(   
                "name" => $this->input->post('member_name'),
                "email" => $this->input->post('email'),
                "tel" => $this->input->post('phone')
            );
            $this->db->where("id", $id);
            $this->db->update('member', $arr);
            redirect("member", "refresh");
            exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = $id"; //SELECT
    $rs = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($rs->num_rows() == 0)  //check the exist of data
    {
        $result['fetch'] = array();
    }
    else
    {
        $data['fetch'] = $rs->row_array(); // just fetch one row
        return $data['fetch'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this code

public function editMember($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = $id"; //SELECT
    $rs = $this->db->query($sql);

    //UPDATE 
    if($this->input->post("btn") != null)
    {
        $arr = array(   
                "name" => $this->input->post('member_name'),
                "email" => $this->input->post('email'),
                "tel" => $this->input->post('phone')
            );
            $this->db->where("id", $id);
            $this->db->update('member', $arr);
            redirect("member", "refresh");
            exit();
    }

    if($rs->num_rows() > 0)  //check the exist of data
    {
        $data['fetch'] = $rs->row_array(); // just fetch one row
    }


    $this->load->view('your_editpage.php',$data);
}
```